# GIT mvn issues with "mvn install"

Tags: git, maven

I am having trouble using maven install through git bash. I am trying to create jars of droid Fu. and everytime I enter `mvn install` from the instructions here.. https://github.com/gradha/droid-fu.

EDITE:WHAT I DID TO TRY TO INSTALL MAVEN

I downloaded appache put it in my program files folder of C Drive.

I created a **user** variable called M2 with the variable of %M2_HOME%.

created a Path in **user** variable pointing to my java sdk\bin

In **system variables** i created a variable called MAVEN_HOME pointing to my C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.0.3\apache-maven

Another one in system variable called JAVA_HOME pointing to my java jdk.

Thats all i did.

Comment: Can you please describe the actual problem? What is expected, what is actually happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git has nothing to do with Maven.

Git is a version control system.
Maven ist a java build tool.

What for problems you have?
Are you have installed (Java and) [Maven?](http://maven.apache.org/download.html)
You already include Maven into your PATH to have access for the command `mvn` in every directory?
When yes, you should type in your console: `mvn --version`
and get something like this:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.2 (r1056850; 2011-01-09 01:58:10+0100)
Java version: 1.6.0_24, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.6.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: Ive downloaded maven from the apache site but i dont know how to install it. I have no idea how to include maven into my PATH? Could you give me the steps i need to take from the Droid Fu instructions? All the help you are giving is greatly appreciated man. Alot of people here think my question is stupid. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: The link to maven (in my answer) contains an installtion instruction, read it! When you don't understand, try this [Java Path](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) And when you even don't understand it, read the wikipeida article [Environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)

Comment: C:\Users\user>mvn --version
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  Is what it keep giving me. I followed all the instructions

Comment: which instructions do you follow? describe exactly what you did

Comment: You are using windows right? First of all: you should extend your existing environment variables like PATH not overwrite it. Second: You say sometimes `variables` another time `system variables`? This all should be system variables unless you don't have admin permisssions (then you can use user variables). Whats your output when you type in your console `echo %PATH%` ? [It should look like this image](http://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/92504215/Windows_XP_Environment_Variables.png?version=1&modificationDate=1199944722810)